# error in flutter [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (15393) crash detected (code -1)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I go back to the previous page, I get the following error:

The entire code is too long, so I'm attaching only the dispose code.

The page where the above error appears is a list view that supports recording, YouTube video, and speech-to-text.

I couldn't find any information about the error below.

```
[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (15393) crash detected (code -1).



  void dispose() {
    _recorder.stop();
    _audioStreamSubscription?.cancel();
    _audioStream?.close();
    controller.dispose();

    appDir = null;
    _currentStatus = RecordingStatus.Unset;
    audioRecorder = null;
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```